# User Stories and Use case scenario

Tags: language-agnostic

What is the difference between User Stories and Use case scenario , purpose-wise ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Cases are more like a [contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) while Use Stories are a planning tool. Consequently, Use Cases usually outlive User Stories since they (should) serve as documentation that concretely reflects the built system.

User stories are written by the customer/stakeholder/client/user. User stories aren't very detailed and are relatively open to interpretation.

Use cases are more formal in structure and are often written by a someone on the team - requirements engineer/product manager. They are often more detailed, breaking down an interaction into individual steps, and clearly identifying pre-conditions and post-conditions such as failure conditions and success conditions.

While one Use Case can cover many scenarios - success and failure; validation errors; sub use-cases and extensions - a User Story is more limited in scope, usually describing a single scenario.

See also [User_story#Comparing_with_use_cases on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story#Comparing_with_use_cases), as well as the chapter "What Use Cases are Not" in the book [User Stories Applied](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321205685).

Lastly, [according to Allistair Cockburn...](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Stop+confusing+use+cases+and+user+stories)

> A user story is synonymous with “feature” as used in the 1990s, a marker for what is to be built, fine-grained enough to fit into modern iteration/sprint periods.
>
> A use case provides a contextual view of what is to be built, serving to bind the organization together, among other things.

Comment: In my opinion you have several mistakes in your opening - User Stories are not a planning tool. They are the informal description of the system functionality as provided by the customer. Use Cases are not a contract but a formal derivation of system behavior based on user stories. Contract is an unrelated term of software design.

Comment: @icepack - Citation, please? My opinions are lifted from the web sites and books I've referred to.

Comment: your own link to wikipedia is a good place to start. I agree with your answer except for the first paragraph for the reasons I've stated

Comment: Is it a good practice to build use cases against a user story to have both high level and low-level details of requirements ?

I could have created a separate question for this, but then I thought the comments would make more sense here,

Answer (score 4):

> "A user story is to a use case as a gazelle is to a gazebo." -- Cockburn

**User Stories** (opposed to requirements) are brief statements of intent that describe *something the system needs to do for some user*. It's a primary technique used by *agile teams* to understand and communicate customer requirements. It’s certainly a handy construct, and small user stories help us drive the extreme instrumentalism that characterizes agile development.

**Use Cases** are a traditional way to express system behavior in complex systems. Use cases are the primary means to represent requirements with the UML. They are well described there as well as in a variety of texts on the subject. *Use cases can be used for both specification and analysis*. They are especially useful when the system of interest is in turn composed of other subsystems.

Books I recommend:

- Agile Software Requirements (Dean Leffingwell)
- Writing Effective Use Cases (Alistair Cockburn)

Comment: The Cockburn quote is silly.  They are different concepts, but they are not completely unrelated to each other.